# How to execute "org.eclipse.ui.file.closeAll" command?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I tried

```java
IHandlerService handlerService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService( IHandlerService.class ) ;
ICommandService commandService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService( ICommandService.class ) ;
Command command = commandService.getCommand( "org.eclipse.ui.file.closeAll" ) ;
command.executeWithChecks( handlerService.createExecutionEvent( command, new Event() ) ) ;
```

but it throws `org.eclipse.core.commands.NotEnabledException`.

There is a method `org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.setEnabled(Object)`, I tried

```java
command.setEnabled( null ) ;
```

but it still didn't work. If the parameter is not passed `null`, what is passed ?

In addition, I tried

```java
IHandlerService handlerService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService( IHandlerService.class ) ;
handlerService.executeCommand( "org.eclipse.ui.file.closeAll", new Event() ) ;
```

It didn't work out either.

Comment: You're already calling `PlatformUI.getWorkbench()` programmatically, so why not continue on to get the current window, its active page, and then tell the page to close all the editors?

Comment: Here I simplify the process of getting this command, I can't actually get the `workbench`.  Here, I have to use this command to close all the editors.

Comment: The _close all_ command closes all editors of the active window, not of all windows. The Javadoc for `setEnabled(null);` says _"May be `null` which indicates that the handler can query whatever model that is necessary."_ So, `setEnabled(null);` has no effect. To my understanding, the enablement of the _close all_ command is done by `org.eclipse.ui.internal.CloseAllHandler.getEnabledWhenExpression()`.